# mysql 'order by' issue with arabic letters

Tags: mysql

I have Arabic words in my database:

Example:

```
أحمد يحيى
احمد اسعد
```

The question is:

I want to get the names sorted by name.

The expected result is:

```
احمد اسعد
أحمد يحيى
```

But I got:

```
أحمد يحيى 
احمد اسعد
```

`أ` before `ا`

I tried this

```
select name from emp order by name;
```

please help.

Comment: select name from emp order by name;

Comment: Can you tell us which character set and collation were used in defining your table?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check your database collations, they should either be set to utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci. This should let you perform order by etc correctly.

If running a stand alone query try this:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
select name from emp order by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a persian collation for your table definition. Example

```
create table emp 
(
   id int,
   name text,
   ...
)
collate utf32_persian_ci;
```

Comment: select name from emp order by replace(name,'ا','أ'');

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solve it by changing the type to `utf16_bin` or any `_bin`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf16_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin;
```

Comment: More details, such as a code example, would be welcomed.